# How to increase time of office 365 push notification web hook verification

Tags: python, flask, outlook, webhooks, office365api

According to microsoft [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations) I have to follow below steps:

> If the listener service successfully validates the URL, it returns a
>   success response within 5 seconds as follows:
>
> 1. Sets the content type in the response header to text\plain.
> 2. Includes the same validation token in the response body.
> 3. Returns an HTTP 200 response code. The listener can discard the   validation token subsequently.

My enpoint is look like this:

```
@app.route('/outlook/push', methods=['POST'])
def outlook_push():
   return (request.args.get('validationtoken'), 200, {'Content-Type': 'plain/text'})
```

but this `exceeds` the time `limit(5s)`

I am getting error like this:

```
{'error': {'code': 'ErrorInvalidParameter', 'message': "Notification URL 'https://5cbae04e.ngrok.io/outlook/push?validationtoken=NmIzZDJiMTMtZjhmNy00ZWMwLTg1MDctNDQwMDQ0OWM2NmE1' verification failed 'System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.OData.Model.Notifications.PushNotification.PushSubscriptionCallbackUrlValidationHelper.SendRequestAndVerifyResponse(Uri callbackUrl, PushSubscription pushSubscription)'."}}
```

**Is there anyway to increase time limit?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be changed, and your problem probably is that your route is defined to accept POST method. And office365 is making GET request in there :)